# Deluge bittorent not seeding properly

Tags: bittorrent, deluge

I've recently been seeding a torrent I uploaded, and it appears all of the downloaders are stuck at either 0.49% or 41.54% progress. Meanwhile on the website the torrent is posted on, it shows there are 0 Seeders.

Is there some sort of router configuration I need to be using, or anything else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like it's a bad torrent - One that's been deliberately uploaded while incomplete, so it'll never finish. The fact there's no seeders means there's no one with a full copy online.

Comment: @djsmiley2k I may not have clarified well enough; I'm the "owner" of the torrent. There are about 30 people trying to download, but they're all stuck at specific numbers

Comment: Ah sorry, missed that. I can only suggest that the creation failed possibly?

Comment: Maybe the torrent has somehow got corrupted on your system. Try to **Stop** it and do a **Force Re-Check**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by downloading a completely different Bittorent client (Vuze), attempting a download, copying the file over the Vuze save-file's data, and then allowing it to seed from there. As of now it appears all of the clients have been able to download the file

Upon further investigation, I'm stupid. My Network settings in deluge were completely messed up, and did not allow upload of files.